# How to add scene after build and deployed in Unity?

Tags: unity, maps, scene, levels

I want to be able to make new levels after build. I could use a map tool and script but I rather just add scene with all the resource packed with it. But what is the best practice forward?

Comment: Have you tried [SceneManager.CreateScene](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.CreateScene.html)

Comment: Is that not only for creating a new one at runtime but how do I add the external pack and how do I complie that pack?

Comment: Then you probably want Asset Bundles, and if you’re on 2019.3 make sure to have a look at Addressables.

Comment: Interesting could you elaborate some more on your thought pattern? I thought asset bundles is what you download from the asset store?

Comment: Ah now I get it. Thank you. I did read some reading on the topic.

Comment: If you've solved your problem, please post an answer describing your solution so others can learn from it (and give you upvotes for a clear explanation!)

Comment: Will do when by computer.